# Adding Features with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm new to PyQGIS and I'm having some dificulties. I'm trying to implement / utilize "Add Feature" (polyline) functionality in my python plugin. 
I know I can do this by defining starting and ending points.

PyQGIS, construct a polyline:

```
line_start = QgsPoint(50,50)
line_end = QgsPoint(100,150)
line = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([line_start,line_end])
```

This is what I'm trying to avoid. I'd like user to digitize / create polyline by clicking on map canvas to preview geometry. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to enable an edit session over a polyline layer you already have or do you want to allow the user to digitize a temporal polyline (e.g, like the one you can see while measuring distances) on map canvas?

Comment: @GermánCarrillo . Yes, I want to digitize / edit on the existing polyline layer on map canvas (not the temporal polyline).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start an edit session on your line layer and activate the `Add Feature` tool by including this code in your plugin:

```
layer = self.iface.activeLayer() # See the note below...
layer.startEditing()
self.iface.actionAddFeature().trigger()
```

*NOTE: the way you access the line layer might differ in your case. You could, for instance, [get the layer by name](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136861/how-to-get-a-layer-by-name-in-pyqgis/136879#136879) (if it's already loaded into QGIS) or even [load it by yourself](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#vector-layers), providing a URI, name, and data provider.*

If you want to save the edits made to the line layer also from your plugin, you can call:

```
layer.commitChanges()
```

On the other hand, if you want to revert any edit made on the layer since you called `startEditing()`, you can call:

```
layer.rollBack()
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: What do you think about QgsRubberBand for drawing polyline and polygon? http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/canvas.html#rubber-bands-and-vertex-markers

Comment: If you need a temporal geometry on the screen, QgsRubberBand is a great alternative. Everything depends on what you actually need.