# Getting layer by name using PyQGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, layer-name

How do I get the layer by name using PyQGIS 3?

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136861/getting-layer-by-name-in-pyqgis/136879#136879

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are sure there is one layer named `LAYER_NAME`, the shortest way:

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('LAYER_NAME')[0]
```

In that way, you can get a layer in a group layer.

```
print(layer)
# OUT: <qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at ...>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
listLayers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('layername')
```

Retrieve a list of matching registered layers by layer name.