# Returning correct layer name in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, toolbox

I have seen this type of question posed a few times on this site. The solutions that I have gleamed from these questions has helped me. But I have not been able to get my script to produce a result that I would like.

I have a layer in my QGIS 3.10 map called **"warn"**, the actual file path and name is **"C:\temp\warn1.shp"**. I am writing a Toolbox to perform a series of processes on this "warn"-file, with the intention that this file will be called something different in the future.

**Some Examples that I have used:**

- [Getting layer by name in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136861/getting-layer-by-name-in-pyqgis)
- [Activating layer by its name in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165415/activating-layer-by-its-name-in-pyqgis)
- [How get layer by name in PyQGIS 3.0?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278920/how-get-layer-by-name-in-pyqgis-3-0/278924)

I set up the parameters for the Toolbox as described in the QGIS Template:

```py
self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                'INPUT',
                self.tr('Area'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon]
            )
        )
```

I call this input in the main script:

```py
Polygon = parameters['INPUT']
```

When I try and confirm the name of the input using a print statement, a value is returned, but the name contains what appears to be an identifier:

```py
print (Polygon)
```

Returns:

> warn1_940166d7_22bc_47bf_b76c_d75462802047

When I use the Polygon variable in the definition of the layer:

```py
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(Polygon)[0]
```

I get an `"index out of range"` error. Which is expected, as the name does not exist in the map.

How can I return the name of the layer, as it appears in Layer View (Table of Contents)?

In this case I would like "warn" returned.

Comment: `layer_name = Polygon.split("_")[0]` ?

Comment: @J.Monticolo thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately in some of the tests I have done, the name might be two words or one. I know I could force it one way or the other, but that would be my last option. I would still prefer the ability to get the name as it appears in the ToC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've achieved this by a little workaround :

```py
from qgis.utils import iface  # add this in the list of imports
#
#
class My_model(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        # ...

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # ...
        lyr_list = iface.layerTreeView().layerTreeModel().rootGroup().layerOrder()
        lyr_dict = {lyr.id(): (lyr.name(), lyr) for lyr in lyr_list}
        if parameters['INPUT'] in lyr_dict:
                print(lyr_dict[parameters['INPUT']][0])
                polygon = lyr_dict[parameters['INPUT']][0]
                layer = lyr_dict[parameters['INPUT']][1]
```

Comment: I used your code and included:
if parameters['INPUT'] in lyr_dict:
                print(lyr_dict[parameters['INPUT']])
                layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(lyr_dict[parameters['INPUT']])[0]

Comment: @KeaganAllan: I improved the answer, from the `lyr_list`, you can access directly to the layers, so I construct a tuple with it.

Answer (score 2):

@Keagan Allan answered to his own question

> Using the accepted answer I added the following to my code:
>
> ```py
> lyr_list = iface.layerTreeView().layerTreeModel().rootGroup().layerOrder()
> lyr_dict = {lyr.id(): lyr.name() for lyr in lyr_list}
> if parameters['INPUT'] in lyr_dict:
>       print(lyr_dict[parameters['INPUT']])
>       polygon = lyr_dict[parameters['INPUT']]
>       layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(polygon)[0]
> ```