# Syntax error using layer.getFeatures PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I am simply trying to run a command in QGIS to extract the coordinates of a point layer, but I get a syntax error when trying to do so (see code below). I can not see where the issue is - any suggestions?

```
for f in layer.getFeatures():
  geom = f.geometry()
  print geom.asPoint()
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 63, in runsource
    code = self.compile(source, filename, symbol)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\codeop.py", line 168, in __call__
    return _maybe_compile(self.compiler, source, filename, symbol)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\codeop.py", line 99, in _maybe_compile
    raise err1
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\codeop.py", line 87, in _maybe_compile
    code1 = compiler(source + "\n", filename, symbol)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\codeop.py", line 133, in __call__
    codeob = compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags, 1)
  File "<input>", line 3
    print geom.asPoint()
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: For Python 3.x your syntax needs to be `print(geom.asPoint())`.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by PolyGeo in his comment, [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) is now a true [function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp), so in [Python 3](https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.0/) you have to call it with its arguments given in parenthesis otherwise such error will be raised:

```
print "Hello world"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 64, in runsource
    code = self.compile(source, filename, symbol)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codeop.py", line 168, in __call__
    return _maybe_compile(self.compiler, source, filename, symbol)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codeop.py", line 99, in _maybe_compile
    raise err1
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codeop.py", line 87, in _maybe_compile
    code1 = compiler(source + "\n", filename, symbol)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codeop.py", line 133, in __call__
    codeob = compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags, 1)
  File "<input>", line 1
    print "Hello world"
                      ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Hello world")?
```

Hence, your code should be:

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('my_layer')[0] 
# [0] because the result is a list, so I have to take its first element.
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    geom = f.geometry()
    print(geom.asPoint())
```

Which results in:

```
<QgsPointXY: POINT(852.5430 508.0729)>
<QgsPointXY: POINT(091.4880 580.0480)>
(...)
```

If you don't actually call the `.asPoint()` method, e.g. by forgetting the parentheses, here's what happens:

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('my_layer')[0] 
# [0] because the result is a list, so I have to take its first element.
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    geom = f.geometry()
    print(geom.asPoint) # parentheses forgotten here!
```

Which doesn't raise an error but which results in this:

```
<built-in method asPoint of QgsGeometry object at 0x7fd1231a5558>
<built-in method asPoint of QgsGeometry object at 0x7fd1231a5d38>
(...)
```

I'm working on QGIS 3.12.1 and Python 3.6.9 at the time I wrote this answer.

#### Check for Python version inside QGIS

This is how I know my Python version from the Python console inside QGIS itself:

```
import sys
sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=9, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

And here's how you can get a layer by its name:
[Getting layer by name in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136861/getting-layer-by-name-in-pyqgis)